# Wygwam upload directory to with MSM problems

Tags: pixelandtonic, wygwam, multi-site-manager

I have a site that seems to be having problems with the Wygwam upload directory. It is a MSM site so there are about 4 sites total. Each site has it's own upload directory on the server.

The problem is when I change the upload directory on one site it changes the main sites upload directory. This is the first time that I have ran into this problem. Has anyone else ran into this problem? Also how do I fix it?

The version of Expression Engine for the site is 2.5.2 and the Wygwam version is 2.7.

Answer (score 1):

When you say, "when I change the upload directory on one site it changes the main site's upload directory," are you referring to the upload directory setting in the Wygwam editor configurations (see image)?

[image: Wygwam Configurations Settings]

If so, you should then just **create a unique editor configuration for each site** so that you can assign a different upload directory for each.